# react-table with 75k+ rows is very slow and CPU-expensive

Tags: react-table

I have loaded a simple react-table component with 75k lines (in 6 columns) as per the "simple table" example at https://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table.

The data source is being loaded into a Redux store and is fully loaded before the table component renders. Once loaded, the react-table is sluggish - if I click "next", I see the next page of data, but have to wait 7-10 seconds while the CPU churns before I can click "next" or "previous" again.

I do not require any type of sorting for this data set but do plan to use the filtering functions of react-table. The component is not crashing in any way and seems to work well - is there anything I can do to speed it up and stop it from hogging the CPU? Is some background sorting operation eating up cycles or something? Suggestions welcome!

Is anyone else loading large data sets into a react-table component? Trying to avoid writing my own component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overcomplex set of filters combined with a sluggish i5. No problems with `react-table`.